# How to conditionally check width

Tags: sass

How can I conditionally check the width of a div and if a div is a certain width I then

```
display: none
```

I am not too sure how to do this in Sass

Comment: You can't, this is not how CSS works. (SASS get's compiled to CSS, the browser doesn't know anything about SASS)

Comment: You can escape the JavaScript route with media queries, but that checks the width of the entire window. Otherwise you'll need JavaScript to measure the width and either apply a class or hide it from the DOM completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for
[Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). However, they are not supported by any [browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=container%20queries) as of now. You can use either Javascript or media queries to conditionally check the width of a div.